# IntelliJ Tomcat deployment with large resources

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm developing a web application using IntelliJ 13 Ultimate and want to run it on a tomcat (7.0.50).

Everything works as it should, but now I need to include a huge amount of images (500k / 3,5 GB) and as I am writing this, my IntelliJ is still copying the files. I am not sure weather it really takes this long or it just died and doesn't tell me. All it says is: "Building artifact ':war exploded': copying files..."

Is there a way to link the resources so that they will not be copied on server startup?

Answer (score 2):

Don't let IntelliJ build the artifact prior deployment. In the **"Server Run Configuration"** there is a configuration **"Before Launch"**. Remove the build task and just build the artifact prior launching your application, using Maven or whatever.

Also, is it really necessary to include so many images within your application? Are these images really a part of your app or just part of the data you create/collect with your app. If the later shouldn't these be stored in an seperate folder you app has access too?